# Extender controls may not be registered before PreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The following code lies inside the Login.aspx file. Previously the code run very smoothly. 
However, upon adding the ajax ModalPopup extender this error occured.

I am trying to create a pop-up when user click the hyperlink "Forget Password".

Previously, I had tried ajax calender and balloonpopup at another aspx file and it works perfectly. Only the modalpopup extender have error.

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Extender controls may not be registered before PreRender.]
   System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.RegisterExtenderControl(TExtenderControl extenderControl, Control targetControl) +442081
```

This is the code inside the Login.aspx file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Forget Password</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="HyperLink2_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="HyperLink2" 
        PopupControlID="Panel1">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> Show pop Up here! </asp:Panel>
```

What was wrong with my code? I had compare it with a sample code from the internet, and it was quite similar.

Answer (score 7):

One reason that could cause this is that you are missing a

```
base.OnPreRender(e);
```

if you have overriden it in your page.